# How to share npm modules across projects?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, dropbox

I'm using windows 10 x64. 
I'm using dropbox to hold all my projects, and having a 'node_modules' folder inside a dropbox folder is a disaster.

First of all not all npm packages work in a way that would allow [this method](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) , because as it says in line one " **does not begin with '/', '../', or './'** ", so that won't work I think.

So, I tried to make syslink, but as I figured out, windows doesn't allow creating true hard links for folders, only files.

My method to create a folder junction was to have this bat file inside each project folder, and run it as administrator.

```
SET dest=%~dp0node_modules
SET src=F:\work\node_modules
MKLINK /J %dest% %src%
```

The bat file works, it creates the syslink, but 3 problems occur.

1. Dropbox sees it as a real folder and starts syncing it.
2. That folder doesn't show in the selective syncing to prevent syncing it.
3. npm can't use it for some reason and when I run 'npm install', It creates a new real 'node_modules' folder to replace the syslink, I get this error output:
   [image: error output]

Comment: I'd suggest you move to [github](https://github.com/), [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or any other versioning system. Do not use Dropbox, Google Drive or any other cloud storage for your code.

Comment: Why are you even using `dropbox` in the first place? `NPM` is probably one of the best tools nowadays( my personal opinion). Just use your `package.json` file to install the *node_modules* for each project?

Comment: @ZombieChowder that is precisely what I don't want to do. many of my projects use common modules.

Comment: It's not very clear what the original problem was. Are you trying to save some dropbox space by sharing modules between projects?

Comment: @mihai exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to use junctions, they are pretty hard to work with and can lead to data loss if you don't know what you're doing.

Instead, you could go with the following approach.

Create a json config file containing the path to your modules:

```
{"modules_root": "F:/work/node_modules/"}
```

In your code, load this json and require your modules by prepending the path from your config file:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var modules_root = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("modules_root.json")).modules_root;
var express = require(modules_root + "./express")
```

If you ever decide to use local modules, you could just change the config file to:

```
{modules_root: "./node_modules/"}
```